# Error in submitting form using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, validation

For some reason, the form is not getting submitted. I have used ajax form to save the form details in my database.

Here is the site link:
    http://www.famproperties.com/mudon/Abu-Dhabi/villas.html

Here is the script code.

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit-form-button").click(function() { submitForm(); });
});
function submitForm() {

    if ( $("#NAME").val() == '' ||
  $("#EMAIL").val()  == '' ||
  $("#MOBILE").val()   == '' ||
  $("#NOTE").val() == '' )
  { alert ("All field are required");}
else {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://famproperties.com/real_estate/property/contact/lead/",
      data: {  
   NAME:   $("#NAME").val(), 
   EMAIL:  $("#EMAIL").val(), 
   MOBILE: $("#MOBILE").val(), 
   NOTE:   $("#NOTE").val(),
   SOURCE: 'MSB.COM'
   },
      success: function() {
         alert("Thanks, Our specialist will contact you soon.");
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });
  $("#NAME").val(''); 
  $("#EMAIL").val(''); 
  $("#MOBILE").val(''); 
  $("#NOTE").val('');
}};

</script>
```

Here is the form code.

```
<!--NEW FORM -->
                        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://famproperties.com/real_estate/property/contact/lead/" autocomplete="on" id="pro-form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="NAME" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NAME" required="" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="EMAIL" class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="EMAIL" required="" placeholder="me@example.com">
                    </div>
                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="MOBILE" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mobile</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="phone" class="form-control inputs" id="MOBILE" required="" placeholder="Mobile">
                    </div>
                </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="NOTE" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NOTE" required="" placeholder="Note">
                    </div>
                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

<a href="#" onclick="return false" class="btn btn-default  btn-lg button" id="submit-form-button" style="background-color: #ffc600;
color: #2a292a;
width: 100%;"> Submit <span class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-1x"></span><span class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-1x"></span>  </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!--NEW FORM-->
```

Comment: Code should be included in the question.

Comment: I already noticed ;-)

Comment: Are you able to find the error of why the page is not submitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the page on http://www.famproperties.com/mudon/Abu-Dhabi/villas.html you are not even loading jquery check the console and youll see this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Thats why ajax is not working

Edit: Sorry, checking your code again i saw you are loading jQuery but you are trying to use jQuery before loading it. So, try moving the jquery script tag to the header or move your js below the jQuery script tag.

Comment: Which jquery code? Because I am using alot of them.

Comment: -.- i mean the jquery library: jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Comment: np, remember to always check the console, whenever you have a javascript error ;)